# login into to a website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping, popup

> I am trying to **scrape** some information from the below website. I am new to this so dont fully understand what is happening. I have basically been sourcing information from various examples i have found on internet
> I am using selenium and python to help me navigate to the page from where i can **scrape** some information
> I have used the below script
> I am able to navigate to the home page , close cookies and click on sign in .
> at this point a pop up opens up for entering user id and password
> the div element is not being identified , each time i get error saying no such element is present
> i added the wait with expected conditions , however i get the below error

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\SeleniumWebscraper2.py:14: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:2672/devtools/browser/f6aca700-5569-4367-9ceb-71e88fcc3082
CDwindow-BD7440D2580236DB9EEFE8B8FE1730D6
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\SeleniumWebscraper2.py", line 37, in 
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='gigya-input-text']").send_keys('x14127032@student.ncirl.ie')
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='gigya-input-text']"}
(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
https://education.independent.ie/league

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://education.independent.ie/league/school/abbey-community-college-roscommon-558")

browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

selector = ".gigya-input-text"


main_window_handle = None
while not main_window_handle:
    main_window_handle = browser.current_window_handle
    print(main_window_handle)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='qc-cmp-button']").click()


WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.current_window_handle)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button-b gigya-sign-in']").send_keys('\n')


WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector )))
print(len(browser.find_elements_by_id("gigya-input-text")))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='gigya-input-text']").send_keys('x14127032@student.ncirl.ie')
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
# import web driver
from selenium import webdriver

# specifies the path to the chromedriver.exe
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/opt/anaconda2/chromedriver")

# driver.get method() will navigate to a page given by the URL address
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login?") 


# locate email form by_name
username = driver.find_element_by_name('session_key')

# locate email form by_xpath
#username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')

# locate email form by_id
#username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")

#send_keys() to simulate key strokes
username.send_keys("username@email.com")

# locate password form by_name
#password = driver.find_element_by_name('session_password')

#locate password form id
#password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

#locate password form by_xpath
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')


# send_keys() to simulate key strokes
password.send_keys("password")

# locate submit button by_class_name
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn__primary--large')

# locate submit button by_xpath
#log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="submit"]')

# .click() to mimic button click
log_in_button.click()
```

Comment: i think this won't work, as i am not able to locate the element which has login credentials

Comment: https://github.com/alokm014/Automate-linkedIn-login check this

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the part of id `gig_1574604202288_showScreenSet` that your are trying to find is random. You can use other selector to locate this element e.g. `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='showScreenSet']")`. You can read about this more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and practice [here](https://flukeout.github.io/).

Also `WebDriverWait(browser, 120)` does nothing. If you want global wait you can use implicit wait. Read about this [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: i added a CSS selector, I still get the error that the element cant be found. Would it be possible to see if you are able to decode and login in to this website